# onClick event don't work Android

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, spinner

I have an error, pretty common as I have seen several solutions, all the same on the internet. I have tried to do this on my android code but it doesn't work.

I have a button. This button, depending on what text is on a spinner, is supposed to make me go to a page or another.

This is the xml code of the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lancer"
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="jumpTo"/>
```

and its java class:

```
public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Spinner spinner_event;
Spinner spinner_activity;
Spinner spinner_wallpaper;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_wallpaper;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_event;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_activity;
Button startButton;
String textActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_admin);


    spinner_event = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_event);
    adapter_event = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.events,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_event.setAdapter(adapter_event);


    spinner_activity = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_activity);
    adapter_activity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_activity.setAdapter(adapter_activity);


    spinner_wallpaper = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_wallpaper);
    adapter_wallpaper = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.wallpapers,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_wallpaper.setAdapter(adapter_wallpaper);

    startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    textActivity = spinner_activity.getSelectedItem().toString();
    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.startButton:
        {
            if(textActivity == "Entree"){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, BadgeEntree.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am supposed to go to my BadgeEntree. Both of them are defined on the AndroidManifest.xml, I am pretty lost everything seems is ok but it isn't, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: As you are already implementing View.OnClickListene, you don't have to add onClick tag inside button xml code.

Comment: I had mo change `textActivity == "Entree"` and delete the `android:onClick="jumpTo"` and It worked. Btw, your solution worked too InteeliJ Amiya, thanks for all. I'll check to close the subject, thanks you everyone!

Comment: In my case, as I have only one button, I'll use yours IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove**

```
     startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    textActivity = spinner_activity.getSelectedItem().toString();
    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.startButton:
        {
            if(textActivity == "Entree"){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, BadgeEntree.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Do**

At first You should call `if(textActivity.equals("Entree")` instead of `==`

### FYI

> Now, when you clicks the button, the Android system calls the
>   activity's jumpTo(View) method. In order for this to work, the method
>   must be public and accept a View as its only parameter.

```
public void jumpTo(View i)
{
textActivity = spinner_activity.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(textActivity.equals("Entree"){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, BadgeEntree.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
            Log.d("Else","Wrong");
            }
}
```

**Finally**

```
public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity  {

Spinner spinner_event;
Spinner spinner_activity;
Spinner spinner_wallpaper;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_wallpaper;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_event;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_activity;
Button startButton;
String textActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_admin);


    spinner_event = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_event);
    adapter_event = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.events,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_event.setAdapter(adapter_event);


    spinner_activity = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_activity);
    adapter_activity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_activity.setAdapter(adapter_activity);


    spinner_wallpaper = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_wallpaper);
    adapter_wallpaper = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.wallpapers,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_wallpaper.setAdapter(adapter_wallpaper);

    startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    }


public void jumpTo(View i)
{
textActivity = spinner_activity.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(textActivity.equals("Entree"){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, BadgeEntree.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
            Log.d("Else","Wrong");
            }
}


}
```

Comment: Let me feedback please.

Comment: @Flo As your wish :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove **onClick tag** from your button xml code

Answer (score 1):

Remove android:onClick="jumpTo" in xml

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/lancer"
android:id="@+id/startButton"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must delete this line

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lancer"
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="jumpTo" <-----
```

/>

and move logic for jumpTo method in your class because now you have onCLick listener in you class and in your xml. Also change this line

```
if(textActivity == "Entree")
```

with this..

```
if(textActivity.equals("Entree"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textActivity == "Entree")
```

change above code to

`if(textActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("Entree"))`

also remove below code from ur xml

```
android:onClick="jumpTo"
```

**NOTE:** You can use "equalsIgnoreCase" if u want Case Insensitive comparison of strings, If You want Case Sensitive comparision of strings then you can use "equals".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm actually trying it too

Comment: I Hope It May Help You :)

Comment: Indeed, and it worked. I won't use it atm because i'm more used to deal with Amiya's way, but it worked, thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear bro and Happy to help u too :) Yes His presentation is good , I din get much time to do that :)